# Iterating through PHP class variables when SplEnum is involved

Tags: php, spl

I'm trying to iterate through the variables within a PHP class that contains an SplEnum. It doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
class enum extends SplEnum { const First = 1; }

class fruit
{
    public $enum;
    public $variable = 2;
    public function __construct(enum $enum)
    {
        $this->enum = $enum;
    }
}

$apple = new fruit(new enum(enum::First));
foreach ($apple as $key => $value) {
    echo "[$key] => $value\n";
}
```

This is the output:

```
[enum] => 1
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'Value not a const in enum enum' in /home/test.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 /home/test.php(16): unknown()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/test.php on line 16
```

It seems that what is happening is that the `foreach` loop is trying to turn each class variable into an `enum`. How do I correctly iterate through the variables in the class?

Answer (score 2):

The SPL Lib is known to be a buggy one.
You can switch the order of the variable declaration to

```
public $variable = 2;
public $enum;
```

And the example will work.
It will also work if you delete the `enum` property declaration altogether.

```
class fruit
{
    public $variable = 2;
    public function __construct(enum $enum)
    {
        $this->enum = $enum;
    }
}
```

Maybe your best bet is to avoid it, or keep it private/protected.

Comment: Thanks; swapping the variable order does solve this particular example. However, I constructed this based on something that is happening with a much more complex set of classes in a project, and re-arranging variables doesn't fix the issue there (and removing the declaration will create confusion). Is there another solution, beyond ditching SplEnum for something else?